# How to scrape Hackerearth pages which are java script protected?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to get Problem Solved in the hackerearth page, for example,
https://www.hackerearth.com/@babe

[image: Hackerearth Page]

When I do inspect element, I get

[image: Inspect Element]

But on doing view source, I cannot find the class dark-weight 700. I think the content is loaded from java script. Therefore, when I use python's bs4 library, it returns me None Element.

I do not want to use selenium because it will open a new browser windows but I am doing all this in DJANGO platform so I want all the scripts to be processed in backend without any interruption and return only the number of problems solved, that is, 119.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the data is loaded via publicly avaliable api (`/users/pagelets/babe/coding-data/` for this user), so you can get the info with `requests` and `bs4`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user = 'babe'
url = 'https://www.hackerearth.com/users/pagelets/{}/coding-data/'.format(user)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
problems_solved = soup.find(string='Problems Solved').find_next().text

print(problems_solved)
```

> 119

Comment: Where can I find more details about this API. Any documentation?

Comment: I have no idea, i found it by inspecting the network traffic. However there is an official api, you'll find the documentation here [https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/legacy/](https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/legacy/)